# How To Display "0000" instead "0" in NumericUpDown in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I want to take 4-digit value from Users using numericUpDown. So, I want to set up "0000" instead "0" to remember them to enter 4-digit.

I am programming WinForm With C#.

I am waiting your help.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: `0000` is not a number; it's a string representation of a number that is left-padded with zeroes to a specific width.. NumericUpDown accepts numbers as input.

Comment: For strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1 - but, as @KenWhite indicated, `0000` is a string, not a number.

Comment: _4-digit value_ There is no such thing for numbers <1000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just override [UpdateEditText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.updateedittext?view=netcore-3.1) and format your value...

[image]

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        this.Text = this.Value.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
    }
    
}
```

Rebuild and your new control should appear in the top of your toolbox.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is exactly what I want !!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, "0000" is a string rather than a number, so that won't really work for a NumericUpDown. The closest solution I can think of would be to create 4 separate NumericUpDowns that accept values 0 through 9 and convert that to your number. Then you could get your 0 0 0 0 to appear and people could move the individual digits up and down. Otherwise I think you would have to use a control that uses strings instead of numbers.