# NumericUpDown allow leading zeros

Tags: winforms

I have `NumericUpDown` control on my form. I set `minimum` to 0 and `maximum` to 999. Nevertheless i want allow the user to put 0 at the beggining for example: 011, 008, 000
Moreover it has to have 3 digits everytime as well. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What `integerInput` control?

Comment: @dr.null apologize, i ment numericUpDown. I've corrected the post

Comment: Yes, makes sense now. See [How To Display "0000" instead "0" in NumericUpDown in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555886/how-to-display-0000-instead-0-in-numericupdown-in-c-sharp). You can do instead `Text = Value.ToString("000");` in the `UpdateEditText` override.